# what version of IE support security="restricted" for iframes

Tags: javascript, html

what version of IE support `security="restricted"` for iframes

and can i use both `security="restricted"` along with  `sandbox="allow-scripts"`. If so which one is taken into account.

Does any other browser otherthan IE support the first one(security).

Comment: http://caniuse.com/iframe-sandbox

Comment: @Adriano i mean security="restricted". So why close request and down vote

Comment: @Adriano you are mistaking me again. i am referring to security="restricted" and not sandbox.

Comment: Sorry, I completely didn't catch the question. No, "restricted" isn't supported by anything else than IE

Comment: @Adriano what all versions and can i use both together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `security` attribute is IE-only. The [Microsoft page on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is vague and describes requirements just as “Minimum supported client: Windows XP, Minimum supported server: Windows 2000 Server”. But in an IEblog posting [Using Frames More Securely](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/01/18/using-frames-more-securely.aspx) from Jan. 2008, a comment refers to it as a feature that “has been supported by the browser for over 7 years now”.

So it seems safe to assume that all versions of IE currently in use support it. And in IE 10, it works even in IE 5 Quirks Mode (which does not prove anything, since the emulation is far from complete, but it *suggests* that the support is old).

There does not seem to be any reason to expect that newer HTML5 attributes would affect the `security` attribute. **Update:** in case specific conflicts, at least on IE 10, `security` seems to take priority, so e.g. `security=restricted sandbox=allow-scripts` makes scripts disallowed.

Comment: IE 10 if i specify both would sandbox one supersed security. (this is what i wnat)

Comment: @WebDeveloper, that’s a different question and should be asked separately. In my tests, it seems that the `security` attribute cannot be removed with a script, so you would probably need to create a new `iframe` element, set suitable properties on it, and replace the markup element with it.